# android livedata Observer didn't notified

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

Hi guys its my first shot to livedata and i will be thankful if you help me to find whats wrong with this Observer

Observer section in my MainActivity can't receive anything, every thing is ok from my Dialogfragment and MainModel class to MainViewModel and I've got triggered logs but nothing happens to Observer in MainActivity

```
class MainModel {
    private var resultLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Course>>()
    private val courseList = ArrayList<Course>()
    private val mainViewModel = MainViewModel()
    fun sum(course: Course) {
        courseList.add(course)
        resultLiveData.value = courseList
        Log.d("tag", "$course in model")
        mainViewModel.loadedResult(resultLiveData)
        Log.d("tag", "${resultLiveData.value} in my model")
    }
}
```

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
     var result = MutableLiveData<List<Course>>()

    fun loadedResult(resultData: MutableLiveData<List<Course>>) {
        result = resultData
        Log.d("tag", "main viewModel ${result.value}")
        Log.d("tag", "main viewModel ${resultData.value}")

    }
}
```

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var fragmentManager: FragmentManager
    private lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        mainRecyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager

        setupLivedata()
        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener {
            showAddDialog()
        }
    }

    private fun setupLivedata() {
        val mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
        var myList : ArrayList<Course>

        var myObserver = Observer<List<Course>> {
            observedList -> myList = observedList as ArrayList<Course>
            Log.d("tag", "${myList.size} reached main activity")
            Log.d("tag", "${observedList.size} reached main activity")

        }
        mainViewModel.result.observe(this, myObserver)
    }

    private fun showAddDialog() {
        val inputDialog = InputDialogFragment()
        inputDialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "input")
    }
}
```

Comment: According your implementation value of `result`never changed. So, How get notified? Call `loadedResult` from your `onCreate` and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing LiveData reference in `MainViewModel` on this line:

`result = resultData`

with LiveData you need to `setValue/postvalue` new items to actually trigger observers.

Something like this:

```java
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
     val result = MediatorLiveData<List<Course>>()

    fun loadedResult(resultData: MutableLiveData<List<Course>>) {
        result.addSource(resultData, { resultObj ->
             result.setValue(resultObj);
        });
        Log.d("tag", "main viewModel ${result.value}")
        Log.d("tag", "main viewModel ${resultData.value}")

    }
}
```

Suggestion: better to keep LiveData immutable and not change it once created. And just update the value.

Comment: thank you for your answer but no such a function like addSource
do i have to create it myself?

Comment: Sorry my bad, had to use MediatorLiveData instead of Mutable for the viewmodel property. I updated my answer now it should be fine

Comment: changed mutableLivedata to mediatorLivedata and by second data insertion from fragment my app crashed and this is the log https://paste.ubuntu.ir/pdyy

Answer (score 2):

`MainModel.mainViewModel` and `MainActivity.mainViewModel` are different instances.

You shouldn't use ViewModel like this

```
private val mainViewModel = MainViewModel()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer
 but how am i supposed to access MainViewModel in my Model class? and send its data to activity

Comment: Receive it as constructor argument or function argument